# статистика telegram бота telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, статистика

хочу в своем боте сделать статистику, но что-то не получается.
код:

```
     sql.execute(f"SELECT alllogsteam FROM infoteam")
 alllogsteam = sql.fetchall()[0][0]
 sql.execute(f"SELECT dateopenteam FROM infoteam")
 dateopenteam = sql.fetchall()[0][0]
 sql.execute(f"SELECT allusersteam FROM infoteam")
 allusers = sql.fetchall()[0][0]
 sql.execute(f"SELECT moneypays FROM users")
 moneypays = sql.fetchall()[0][0]
 sql.execute(f"SELECT status FROM users")
 status = sql.fetchall()[0][0]
 admins = 0
 supports = 0
 workers = 0
 installers = 0
 blocked = 0
 otrabov = 0
 ogidaut = 0
 soplatoizalog = 0
 if soplatoizalog == 1:
  soplatoizalog = soplatoizalog+1
 if status == 0:
  workers = workers+1
 elif status == 1:
  admins = admins+1
 elif status == 2:
  supports = supports+1
 elif status == 3:
  blocked = blocked+1
 elif status == 4:
  installers = installers+1
 elif status == 5:
  otrabov = otrabov+1
 elif status == 999:
  ogidaut = ogidaut+1
 bot.edit_message_text(
 f'''<i> Статистика тимы </i><b>{config.team}:</b>\n\n''' \
 f'''┌ ‍ Всего пользователей: <b>{allusers}</b>\n''' \
 f'''├ ⛏ Воркеров: <b>{workers}</b>\n''' \
 f'''├ ‍✈️ Администраторов: <b>{admins}</b>\n''' \
 f'''├  Саппортов: <b>{supports}</b>\n''' \
 f'''├  Отработчиков: <b>{otrabov}</b>\n''' \
 f'''├  Инсталлеров: <b>{installers}</b>\n''' \
 f'''├ ⛔️ Заблокировано: <b>{blocked}</b>\n''' \
 f'''└ ⏳ Ожидающих: <b>{ogidaut}</b>\n\n''' \
 f'''┌  Всего логов: <b>{alllogsteam}</b>\n''' \
 f'''└  Дата нашего открытия: <b>{dateopenteam}</b>\n''' 
 , call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=ToAdmMenu, parse_mode='HTML')
```

вот что показывает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: нужно чтобы бот смотрел в бд, в таблицу status и если status = 1 у 3 пользователей, то выводил сообщение что есть 3 пользователя с status = 1

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример правильной(на сколько мне известно) работы с данными SQL.
Исходя из этого примера делай свою статистику.

Структура таблицы: id | telegram | is_support | is_admin | balance

```
# Получаем данные из БД.
data = sql.execute('SELECT * FROM users').fetchall()
users = len(data) # Получаем кол-во пользователей.

# Создаём пустые переменные.
admins = 0
support = 0
balance = 0

# Проходимся по всем пользователям, и получаем данные каждого пользователя.
# Так как bool значения храняться в базе в виде 0 или 1 - можем их спокойно прибавлять к переменным.
# "admins += 1" это как "admins = admins + 1"
for user in data:
   admins += user[3] # Получаем кол-во админов.
   support += user[2] # Получаем кол-во саппортов.
   balance += user[4] # Получаем общий баланс пользователей.

print(f'Общая статистика:\n\n'
      f'Пользователей: {users}\n'
      f'Администраторов: {admins}\n'
      f'Саппортов: {support}\n'
      f'Общий баланс: {balance}')
```

Comment: у меня вот такая ошибка выходит:
unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: user[i] оберните в int()

Получиться admins += int(user[3]), и т.д.

Comment: теперь такое 'bool' object has no attribute 'chat'

Comment: объект 'bool' не имеет атрибута 'chat'

Это уже в вашем коде что-то